# Call std::functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to write a class template that would get two `std::function`s in the constructor parameter and call them upon construction and destruction, in a RAII style.

What am I missing?

```
template <class T>
class HelloGoodbye{
public:
HelloGoodbye(std::function<T> const & f, std::function<T> const &g)
  :mf(f),mg(g)
{
  mf();
}


~HelloGoodBye()
{
  mg();
}

private:
std::function<T> mf;
std::function<T> mg;
};


class Printer
{
    public:
    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << "hello!" << std::endl;
    }
    void goodbye()
    {
        std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl;   
    }
};

int main()
{
      Printer p;
      auto hi = std::bind(&Printer::hello, &p);
      auto bye = std::bind(&Printer::goodbye, &p);
      HelloGoodbye hgb(hi,bye);      
}
```

Comment: You don't need to save `mf`.

Answer (score 3):

`HelloGoodbye` is a class template, you need to specify the template argument when use it. e.g.

```
HelloGoodbye<void()> hgb(hi,bye);
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/BBXVQ71704)

BTW: I suppose `~HelloGoodBye()` is a typo of `~HelloGoodbye()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicit the template type of `hgb`, as suggested by songyuanyao, or you can create a make function

```
template <typename T>
HelloGoodbye<T> makeHG (std::function<T> const & hi,
                        std::function<T> const & bye)
 { return { hi, bye }; }
```

and, using `auto`, you can initialize `hgb` as follows

```
auto hgb = makeHG(hi, bye);
```

Unfortunately, `std::bind` is a strange beast with an undefined return value, so you can't pass the type returned from `std::bind` to `makeHG()` to obtain the `T` type deduction.

So, if you want to use `makeHG()`,  you can use `auto` to define `hi` and `bye` but you have to explict the type as follows

```
  std::function<void()> hi = std::bind(&Printer::hello, &p);
  std::function<void()> bye = std::bind(&Printer::goodbye, &p);
```

So, I suppose, the sonyuanyao one is a better solution.

Comment: Once he's using a make function to construct a templated class, he doesn't need the heavy-weight std::function anymore.  He could just template the callable types and store the closing one.

Comment: Considering that `f` and `g` have to be callable with no parameters, we can create the function signature from a `std::bind`; assuming `std::is_bind_expression<T>::value` is `true` and `decltype(std::declval<T>()())` is a valid type, then the signature supplied to `std::function` should be `typename T::result_type()`.  [Like so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89ba8e3b8e14d949).  This is probably somewhat fragile, though, and I have no idea whether it's good practice or not.

Comment: @JustinTime - thanks but... I thougth this solution (and I don't think it's fragile) but, IMHO, isn't interesting; because works only in this particular (no parameters) case; I've searched a more general solution (that is equivalent to write a template "make" function to convert a `std::bind()` returned value to the correspondent `std::function` value detecting it's type) but without success.

Comment: @max66 Ah, okay.  I'm not aware of any ways to get a freestanding function type from any `std::bind`, either, unfortunately.  There's probably some way to do it, but I'm not familiar enough with `bind` to know what it is; I would guess it would involve some kind of template magic to essentially build the parameter list by elimination, but that's just a guess.